# Функция, заменяющая все нечетные вхождения текста строкой1, а все четные - строкой2

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать на javascript функцию, пробегающую тело документа от начала до конца и заменяющую все нечетные вхождения искомой строки `str` на `str1`, а все четные вхождения `str` на `str2`.

Теоретически я понимаю, что нужно запустить некий цикл от начала до конца страницы, и прописать в этом цикле примерно так:

```
count = count +1;
```

Если `count` - нечетное, то заменить текущий элемент на `str1`
Если `count` - четное, то заменить текущий элемент на `str2`

Какую команду для этого можно применить?

Comment: На самом деле, я несколько поторопился с ответом. Было бы правильнее разбить исходный вопрос на два: про замену строки и про работу с содержимым страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Если на чистом JavaScript, то примерно так (не тестировал)

```
function replaceWithSelect(pattern, oddStr, evenStr) {
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), // выбираем все теги
        oddFound = false,
        rx = new RegExp((pattern + '').replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&"), "g");
        children,
        node;
    for (var ix = items.length; ix--;) { // обходим все теги
        children = items[ix].childNodes;
        for (var iy = children.length; iy--) { // перебираем все узлы
            node = children[iy];
            if (3 == node.nodeType) { // если узел текстовый
                node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(rx, function() {
                    oddFound = !oddFound;
                    return oddFound ? oddStr : evenStr;
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
replaceWithSelect(str, str1, str2);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :) Хотел уточнить: параметр str в строке node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(str, substitution); нигде ранее не объявляется. Или нужно в str загнать  node.nodeValue до выполнения подстановки?

Comment: @Алексей Это строка которую ищем. Она должна быть задана до вызова приведенного кода. Например можно этот код завернуть в функцию `function (str, str1, str2) {}`. Пожалуй исправлю ответ

Comment: @Алексей ...тем более что в логике замены вкралась ошибка

Comment: +1 - мне понравилась замена строк на регулярное выражение и функцию в `replace` - что позволяет обойтись без цикла. Опять же - репутация округлилась. Надеюсь, что не надолго.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна функция для проверки наличия под-строки.
Вам подойдет `.indexOf`

```
str.indexOf(subStr) //Вернет 0 или больше если под-строка найдена, и -1 если нет ни одного вхождения.
```

Для замены подстроки исползуйте `.replace`

```
str = str.replace(subStr, str1); //заменит первое вхождение подстроки (только первое, остальные останутся не тронутами)
```

Как вы уже написали вам нужен счетчик вхождений. Запускаете цикл `while` и в зависимости от счетчика вызываете `replace` используя `str1` или `str2`.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил, не всегда получается объяснять что бы было всем ясно))

Comment: Кто ясно мыслит - ясно излагает: `str = str.replace(subStr, (count++ % 2 == 0)? str1 : str2);`

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, цикл while пускать по чему? Что в данном случае является признаками начала и останова цикла?

Comment: В моем видении, while запускается по условию str.indexOf(subStr) >= 0, то есть выполнять цикл до тех пор пока есть хоть одна под-строка. Ниже в другом ответе вам привели оптимальный вариант функции.

Answer (score 0):

Если прямо в лоб, то можно целиком текст документа под замену взять. Думаю такой вариант самый быстрый. Вот пример замены четных/нечетных совпадений и замена четных/нечетных совпадений пар (например HTML/XML теги):

```js
/* Замена чет/нечет */
var i = 0; // итератор
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/Заголовок\s\d/g, function(){return (i++ % 2) ? 'Четный' : 'Нечетный'});

/* Пример парных замен, например HTML тегов. 
Т.к. они парные в большинстве своем, то меняем и закрывающие теги.
С случае попадания в выборку не парных тегов, будут не правильные результаты и в таком случае надо рабвивать на 2 вызова replace() и менять сначала открывающие теги, а потом закрывающие */
i = 1; // обнуляем итератор
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/h\d/g, function(){return (++i % 4 >= 2) ? 'h1' : 'h6'});
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок 1</h1>
<h2>Заголовок 2</h2>
<h3>Заголовок 3</h3>
<h4>Заголовок 4</h4>
<h5>Заголовок 5</h5>
<h6>Заголовок 6</h6>
```